# Mathjax not working in browser when hosted on Google Drive

Tags: tex

This is first time I'm driving to use Mathjax, the maths is written in LaTeX, it works fine when I open the page locally, but when I host the same page on Google Drive, Mathjax no longer works, I only see the LaTeX code.

Here is the link to the webpage.

https://googledrive.com/host/0B6DfW2X25tuNck9yLTFSX2hiTEE/Group%20challenge%20Topic%206.html

And here is my code.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6DfW2X25tuNck9yLTFSX2hiTEE&usp=sharing

I have tried everything, I'm using latest Chrome, so it shouldn't have any issues loading Mathjax

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with math.stackexchange. You should probably ask the question on the mathjax mailing list or possibly at support for google drive.

Answer (score 1):

Since Google Drive is using a `https://` URL, you need to load all your resources via `https` as well or you will get a security violation (check the browsers console for these).  So that means you need to use an `https:` URL for MathJax.  The MathJax CDN provides an alternate URL for that:  `https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/`.  See the [MathJax FAQ](http://www.mathjax.org/resources/faqs/#problem-https) for details.